# SIGHUP signal handler reset to default when using system() on embedded linux with busybox

Tags: c, linux, sh, busybox

I am working on an embedded linux with busybox. As part of my application I have a rc.init script E80-startmyprog. That script is calling my program prog.

```sh
trap "" HUP
startmyprog >${LOGFILE} 2>&1 </dev/null &

startmyprog() {
  prog
}
```

In my program I can see that the signal handlers are set to ignore SIGHUP. I am checking that with

```c
struct sigaction act;
sigaction(1, NULL, &act);
printf("action %p\n", act.sa_sigaction);  // prints out 1 -> SIG_IGN
```

Now at some time in my program I need to start another process, give it some input and check if it printed "yes" on stdout. I am using system to do that.

```c
const int ret = system("[ `echo input | second_process` == yes ]");
```

Normal behavior is that `WIFEXITED(ret)` is true and that `WEXITSTATUS(ret)` is 0 or 1.

But in some cases with unfortunate timing `WIFSIGNALED(ret)` is true and `WTERMSIG(ret)` is 1 (SIGHUP).

Debugging shows that if I `execl("second_process", "second_process", (char*)NULL)` the signal handler state in second_process is set correctly to SIGHUP=ignore. But if I use `system`, then second_process has SIGHUP=default.

My questions are:

What is going on there? Who is resetting the SIGHUP signal handler at startup? Is it the shell? Is there a way to prevent that? (In the sh man page I have not seen a command line option that looks so.)

I know I could do a workaround and setup a pipe, fork, exec second_process, write input to pipe, read output from pipe and parse output, but that is a lot of stuff compared to a system one liner and there is good chance that I will miss something and get it wrong.

Comment: Try `strace -ff -o /tmp/foo program` -- this will run strace on your program, following forks, and storing trace results per-process in /tmp/foo.NNNNN. I think you'll find that system(3) is NOT resetting the SIGHUP handler, though perhaps something else is.

Comment: @GilHamilton Good point. Previously I did run strace, but only for slightly other tests. I reran your suggested strace. The logs show that the spawned sh calls rt_sigaction: `rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {0x10000000, [], 0}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_NOCLDSTOP}, 16) = 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging deeper into the sources of the busybox that is running on the Linux I found out that the shell in busybox is calling `signal(SIGHUP, SIG_DFL);` during init. This resets the sighup handler to default. So the shell itself and the program it runs (provided with `-c ...`) are running with default SIGHUP handler.

I see no code path that bypasses resetting the SIGHUP signal handler, so it seems I cannot achieve what I want with `system()`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's exactly what's happening. When you type 'trap' into the shell, you're asking it list the actions it has established for that signal. When you invoke a subshell, you haven't given it any actions, so it won't show any (it doesn't know about what you gave to its parent) but that doesn't mean it has reset the SIGHUP state.

Try this small script that proves SIGHUP is still ignored even though "trap" shows nothing:

```
trap "" HUP
echo "TRAPs in parent"
trap
sh -c 'echo "TRAPs in child"; trap; sleep 5; echo "Still here. Traps: "; trap' &
child=$!
sleep 1
kill -HUP $child
echo 'Killed child'
```

Comment: OK, so my comparison with what I observe with bash is not the same to what I observe with my c program and `system`. I am sorry for that confusion and will delete the bash comparison part.